# understand df.isnull.mean() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df. Code is written in such a manner

`df.isnull().mean().sort_values(ascending = False)`

Here is the some part of the output-

```
inq_fi                                 1.0
sec_app_fico_range_low                 1.0
```

I want to understand how it is working?

if we use, `df.isnull()` only it will return us True or False for each and every cell. How `mean()` is going to give us right output. My objective is to find percentage of null values in all columns. Above output represents inq_fi and sec_app_fico_range_low has all missing values.

Also we are not passing by in sort_values?

Comment: Think about what `mean` is actually doing.  It simply returns the sum of the values divided by the number of values.  When your values are `0-1` (boolean), it returns the percentage of 1s.  Try it on a series with only a couple elements and you'll quickly see the behavior

Answer (score 9):

Breakdown would look like this:

```
df.isnull()
#Mask all values that are NaN as True
df.isnull().mean()
#compute the mean of Boolean mask (True evaluates as 1 and False as 0)
df.isnull().mean().sort_values(ascending = False)
#sort the resulting series by column names descending
```

That being said a column that has values:

```
[np.nan, 2, 3, 4]
```

is evaluated as:

```
[True, False, False, False]
```

interpreted as:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Resulting in:

```
0.25
```